# Cross platform ZIP utility for scripting

Tags: cross-platform, zip

Background: I'm writing a script to collect some files in to a zip file. This script might be used in several operation system. The issue is that I don't what do they(the OS's) support? Linux has a build-in ZIP (on most distributions). Windows is a bit of a mess in this perspective. Since the zip command is not distrusted with the OS

Two issues:
1) I'm looking for a ZIP utility to be my scripts meat and bones, without actually implementing my own zip. Something with a unified command line style. (Java based perhaps?) If you know one, it will help me a lot to complete my task.

2) Right now I'm using some oracle client zip.exe for my windows machine to test my script. I've notice that I don't see the files inside of my newly created archive. Browsing around the web tells me that this has to do with windows being "blind". Preferably, any utility will solve that. Any ideas on why does this happen?

Comment: For Windows, it may be worth investigating 7zip protable(http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/7-zip_portable) if you can't find a unified cross-platform solution.

Comment: InfoZIP is included in the base install of many Linux distros, but others make it optional, and it's certainly not in any sense part of "the core" (whatever that is supposed to mean).

Comment: @sbtkd85 Ive looked in to 7zip products. I'm looking for the same CLI zip utility to run in all OS. This doesn't really cut it

Comment: InfoZIP should certainly be available for DOS / Windows as well (and then some). http://www.info-zip.org/

Comment: I ended up Implementing my own Code using java. this was far easier and does exactly what I wanted it do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the and I wrote a litle program in Java that does the ziping. I would publish the code but it's closed source. Since java was assumed in my system combined with the strong zip power it was the solution.